# Where does the output of a script placed in /etc/cron.hourly go?

Tags: logging, cron, mailbox

1. Say I have a script named "testcron" containing the following:

   `#!/bin/bash
   echo This script ran on $(date)`
2. I then set the permissions: `chmod ug+x testcron`
3. Finally, I copy this script to /etc/cron.hourly
4. And I wait for something to happen at the next hour.

So, I found in the /var/log/cron the following entry:

`Jul 17 12:01:02 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[13218]: starting testcron
Jul 17 12:01:02 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[13240]: finished testcron`

However, I could not find the script's actual output anywhere.  Where does the output of this script go?  Is it mailed?  The root has no mail account. Can I redirect the mail to another user for just this script or will all mail output end up in the user's account?  Does it go to /var/log/messages?  What is the correct way redirect the output to, say, a dedicated log file?

Note: The script I included above doesn't actually do anything useful but I want to adapt the principles to another script that does.

OS: centos 7

Thanks to all in advance,
Allan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS, it doesn’t seem to be logging output anywhere, just the fact that the cron has executed is stored in `/var/log/cron`.

If you need the output, you can use standard shell redirection. First create a file:

`touch /var/log/cronoutput`

Then capture the output of your cron, example:

```
* * * * * echo "hey" >> /var/log/cronoutput
```

Output:

```
tail /var/log/cronoutput
hey
hey
hey
hey
```

Comment: There is no such file on this system.

Comment: There is a file named `/var/log/cron` that contains entries indicating the start and finish of cron jobs but no output from the actual script run.

Comment: Try `/var/log/messages` ?

Comment: That file exists but doen't have the output from the script.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn’t seem that it logs it. You’d have to create your own file to capture the output. Updating my answer.

Comment: If I am understanding your answer correctly, you are showing the entry used for the interactive command, `crontab -e` but I am not using `crontab -e`.  Instead, I am using another script to copy the testcron script to `/etc/cron.hourly` and am trying to avoid any manual interaction.  Is it OK to redirect the output from within the script?

Comment: OK I tried redirecting the output inside the script rather than using crontab -e to specify the redirection and it worked.  So, even though I did not follow notStan's instructions precisely, his answer did lead me to the solution.